# Get element attribute inside jquery $.get request

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

I'm sure there's an easy answer for this, but I'm not sure how to correctly search for what I'm looking for. I'm messing around with Chrome Extensions and I have a point where I need to do an XMLHttpRequest.

Here's what I've got so far.

The request:

```
$.get(details.url, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

This correctly logs the information that I want. However, I don't want all of it, obviously - only part of it. I'd like to use this jquery:

```
$('meta[itemprop=contentURL]').attr('content');
```

To set a variable - something like this:

```
var url = $('meta[itemprop=contentURL]').attr('content');
```

So using the `data` I get back from the request, how would I set a variable of that content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.get(details.url, function(data) {
    var url = $(data).find('meta[itemprop=contentURL]').attr('content');
});
```

Calling `$()` on an HTML string will parse it and produce a jQuery object containing the DOM elements.